# Have a item "quote" for Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I'm creating a website of quotes and some stuff, and I really want to know if schema.org has an item or something for quotes.

I've looked in the schema, but don't found this topic.

Someone knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [draft proposal for a quotation schema](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/QuotationSchema). **Update:** The proposed `Quotation` type is [in Pending currently](http://pending.schema.org/Quotation).

For now, you could simply use [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) and the [`citation` property](http://schema.org/citation).

Answer (score 0):

```
<blockquote itemprop="citation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemid="https://books.google.com/books?id=QpajMuyXG8AC">
With the advent of technology, so increased the ambition to relive the experiences of past Leonid storm observers.
</blockquote>
```